# Filter, merge, sort and page data from multiple sources

Tags: c#, caching, merge, pagination, iqueryable

At the moment I'm retrieving data from the DB through a method that retrieves an `IQueryable<T1>`, filtering, sorting and then paging it (all these on the DB basically), before returning the result to the UI for display in a paged table.

I need to integrate results from another DB, and paging seems to be the main issue.

- models are similar but not identical (same fields, different names, will need to map to a generic domain model before returning);
- joining at the DB level is not possible;
- there are ~1000 records at the moment between both DBs (added during
  the past 18 months), and likely to grow at mostly the same (slow)
  pace;
- results always need to be sorted by 1-2 fields (date-wise).

I'm currently torn between these 2 solutions:

1. Retrieve all data from both sources, merge, sort and then cache them; then simply filter and page on said cache when receiving requests - but I need to invalidate the cache when the collection is modified (which I can);
2. Filter data on each source (again, at the DB level), then retrieve, merge, sort & page them, before returning.

I'm looking to find a decent algorithm performance-wise. The ideal solution would probably be a combination between them (caching + filtering at the DB level), but I haven't wrapped my head around that at the moment.

Comment: The opposite db's contains duplicates?

Comment: negative, no duplicates

Comment: I like your question ;) I did something similar but without paging, I'll try to see if paging can be added to what I had there

Comment: Do you think you need to skip pages? or is suitable to have a previews/next url mechanism?

Comment: at the moment I `Skip|Take`, but I'm not wed to that

Comment: Are you also grouping results, or just filter + sort + page?

Comment: just that, no grouping

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the following algorithm. Suppose your page size is 10, then for page 0:

1. Get 10 results from database A, filtered and sorted at db level.
2. Get 10 results from database B, filtered and sorted at db level (in parallel with the above query)
3. Combine those two results to get 10 records in the correct sort order. So you have 20 records sorted, but take only first 10 of them and display in UI

Then for page 1:

1. Notice how many items from database A and B you used to display in UI at previous step. For example, you used 2 items from database A and 8 items from database B.
2. Get 10 results from database A, filtered and sorted, but starting at position 2 (skip 2), because those two you already have shown in UI.
3. Get 10 results from database B, filtered and sorted, but starting at position 8 (skip 8).
4. Merge the same way as above to get 10 records from 20. Suppose now you used 5 item from A and 5 items from B. Now, in total, you have shown 7 items from A and 13 items from B. Use those numbers for the next step.

This will not allow to (easily) skip pages, but as I understand that is not a requirement.

The perfomance should be effectively the same as when you are querying single database, because queries to A and B can be done in parallel.

Comment: I understand your proposed solution, and thought of it before, but I need to do this in a RESTful manner, and not having to remember individual item indexes - plus, I'd loathe to have to scale that up

Comment: But you need to remember at which page you are on now anyway, why not remember 2 more numbers? You store all that on the client, not on server, so not sure how it is related to RESTful ness

Comment: You probably mean you don't want to add two unclear parameters to your REST api. Well, that might be reasonable. As for scale - pulling all data into memory and working there scales MUCH worse.

Comment: I see an issue with this algorithm, If a database is altered in anyway you will return invalid data for the second/n pagination. Going on your example let's say that between enumerating Page 0 and Page 1 someone inserts a new entry in the first database in the position 0, skipping the first 2 items per this algorithm will exclude the new entry. The same goes for any update/delete operation.

Comment: @mematei not sure that is such a big problem. Any paging algorithm behaves not perfect if data changes in between. Say between page 0 and page 1 in regular single database scenario someone insterts 100 items which are "smaller" than page 0 items ("smaller" in terms of ordering criteria, say have smaller dates). You will never see them while navigating through pages until you refresh, same story here.

Answer (score 0):

I've created something here, I will come back with explications if needed.
I'm not sure my algorithm works correctly for all edge cases, it cover all of the cases what I had in mind, but you never know. I'll leave the code here for your pleasure, I will answer and explain what is done there if you need that, leave a comment.

And perform multiple tests with list of items with large gaps between the values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        //each time when this objects are accessed, consider as a database call
        private static IQueryable<model1> dbsetModel_1; 
        private static IQueryable<model2> dbsetModel_2;

        private static void InitDBSets()
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            List<model1> dbsetModel1 = new List<model1>();
            List<model2> dbsetModel2 = new List<model2>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 300; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    dbsetModel1.Add(new model1() { Id = i, OrderNumber = rnd.Next(1, 10), Name = "Test " + i.ToString() });
                }
                else
                {
                    dbsetModel2.Add(new model2() { Id2 = i, OrderNumber2 = rnd.Next(1, 10), Name2 = "Test " + i.ToString() });
                }
            }
            dbsetModel_1 = dbsetModel1.AsQueryable();
            dbsetModel_2 = dbsetModel2.AsQueryable();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            //generate sort of db data
            InitDBSets();
            //test
            var result2 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 5, Limit = 10 });
            var result3 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 6, Limit = 10 });
            var result5 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 7, Limit = 10 });
            var result6 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 8, Limit = 10 });
            var result7 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 4, Limit = 20 });
            var result8 = GetPage(new PagingFilter() { Page = 200, Limit = 10 });

        }


        private static PagedList<Item> GetPage(PagingFilter filter)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            //load only start pages intervals margins from both database
            //this part need to be transformed in a stored procedure on db one, skip, take to return interval start value for each frame 
            var framesBordersModel1 = new List<Item>();
            dbsetModel_1.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber).ToList().ForEach(i => {
                pos++;
                if (pos - 1 == 0)
                {
                    framesBordersModel1.Add(new Item() { criteria1 = i.Id, criteria2 = i.OrderNumber, model = i });
                }
                else if ((pos - 1) % filter.Limit == 0)
                {
                    framesBordersModel1.Add(new Item() { criteria1 = i.Id, criteria2 = i.OrderNumber, model = i });
                }

            });
            pos = 0;
            //this part need to be transformed in a stored procedure on db two, skip, take to return interval start value for each frame
            var framesBordersModel2 = new List<Item>();
            dbsetModel_2.OrderBy(x => x.Id2).ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber2).ToList().ForEach(i => {
                pos++;
                if (pos - 1 == 0)
                {
                    framesBordersModel2.Add(new Item() { criteria1 = i.Id2, criteria2 = i.OrderNumber2, model = i });
                }
                else if ((pos -1) % filter.Limit == 0)
                {
                    framesBordersModel2.Add(new Item() { criteria1 = i.Id2, criteria2 = i.OrderNumber2, model = i });
                }

            });

            //decide where is the position of your cursor based on start margins
            //int mainCursor = 0;
            int cursor1 = 0;
            int cursor2 = 0;
            //filter pages start from 1, filter.Page cannot be 0, if indeed you have page 0 change a lil' bit he logic 
            if (framesBordersModel1.Count + framesBordersModel2.Count < filter.Page) throw new Exception("Out of range");
            while ( cursor1 + cursor2 < filter.Page -1)
            {
                if (framesBordersModel1[cursor1].criteria1 < framesBordersModel2[cursor2].criteria1)
                {
                    cursor1++;
                }
                else if (framesBordersModel1[cursor1].criteria1 > framesBordersModel2[cursor2].criteria1)
                {
                    cursor2++;
                }
                //you should't get here case main key sound't be duplicate, annyhow
                else
                {
                    if (framesBordersModel1[cursor1].criteria2 < framesBordersModel2[cursor2].criteria2)
                    {
                        cursor1++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cursor2++;
                    }
                }
                //mainCursor++;
            }
            //magic starts
            //inpar skipable
            int skipEndResult = 0;
            List<Item> dbFramesMerged = new List<Item>();
            if ((cursor1 + cursor2) %2 == 0)
            {
                dbFramesMerged.AddRange(
                    dbsetModel_1.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                        .ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber)
                        .Skip(cursor1*filter.Limit)
                        .Take(filter.Limit)
                        .Select(x => new Item() {criteria1 = x.Id, criteria2 = x.OrderNumber, model = x})
                        .ToList()); //consider as db call EF or Stored Procedure
                dbFramesMerged.AddRange(
                    dbsetModel_2.OrderBy(x => x.Id2)
                        .ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber2)
                        .Skip(cursor2*filter.Limit)
                        .Take(filter.Limit)
                        .Select(x => new Item() {criteria1 = x.Id2, criteria2 = x.OrderNumber2, model = x})
                        .ToList());
                ; //consider as db call EF or Stored Procedure
            }
            else
            {
                skipEndResult = filter.Limit;
                if (cursor1 > cursor2)
                {
                    cursor1--;
                }
                else
                {
                    cursor2--;
                }
                dbFramesMerged.AddRange(
                   dbsetModel_1.OrderBy(x => x.Id)
                       .ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber)
                       .Skip(cursor1 * filter.Limit)
                       .Take(filter.Limit)
                       .Select(x => new Item() { criteria1 = x.Id, criteria2 = x.OrderNumber, model = x })
                       .ToList()); //consider as db call EF or Stored Procedure
                dbFramesMerged.AddRange(
                    dbsetModel_2.OrderBy(x => x.Id2)
                        .ThenBy(z => z.OrderNumber2)
                        .Skip(cursor2 * filter.Limit)
                        .Take(filter.Limit)
                        .Select(x => new Item() { criteria1 = x.Id2, criteria2 = x.OrderNumber2, model = x })
                        .ToList());
            }

            IQueryable<Item> qItems = dbFramesMerged.AsQueryable();
            PagedList<Item> result = new PagedList<Item>();
            result.AddRange(qItems.OrderBy(x => x.criteria1).ThenBy(z => z.criteria2).Skip(skipEndResult).Take(filter.Limit).ToList());

            //here again you need db cals to get total count
            result.Total = dbsetModel_1.Count() + dbsetModel_2.Count();
            result.Limit = filter.Limit;
            result.Page = filter.Page;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class PagingFilter
    {
        public int Limit { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
    }



    public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
    {

        public int Total { get; set; }
        public int? Page { get; set; }
        public int? Limit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item : Criteria
    {
        public object model { get; set; }
    }

    public class Criteria
    {
        public int criteria1 { get; set; }
        public int criteria2 { get; set; }
        //more criterias if you need to order
    }

    public class model1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class model2
    {
        public int Id2 { get; set; }
        public int OrderNumber2 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```