# How to efficiently find insertion index using SQL

Tags: sql, binary-search

I have a table which contains a list of names. After sorting this list, I get the following output (in reality thousands of rows):

| # | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | aaaa |
| 1 | bbbb |
| 2 | cccc |
| 3 | dddd |
| 4 | eeee |
| 5 | ffff |

After sorting, I want to find the closest index (`#`) to a given name.

For example:

| Query | Output |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | 0 |
| dddd | 3 |

This could be solved using a simple `WHERE name = $query`. However, I also want this to work when the query string is not part of the result set:

| Query | Output |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 0 |
| aabb | 1 |
| gggg | 6 |

In other words, I want to find the index of the string, or the index at which it should be inserted if the string is not present.

In non-SQL languages, I would achieve this using a binary search (see e.g. python's [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)). How can I do the same in a performant way with SQL?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  You seem to have two ways to represent the same thing.  And you seem concerned about "holes" in the sequencing.  This sounds slow and error prone - can you give us some more details?

Comment: In it's most general form I'm trying to find out if and how [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) can be performed using sql. In my specific case, I want to use this information for pagination. However, that's just one of many potential use cases for this type of algorithm.

Comment: A further concrete example of what this could be used for is [cursor-based pagination](https://medium.com/@george_16060/cursor-based-pagination-with-arbitrary-ordering-b4af6d5e22db) when the data source consists of multiple databases see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523216/filter-merge-sort-and-page-data-from-multiple-sources

Comment: If you want Keyset Pagination, you are overthinking this. A normal index on the columns you want will suffice, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997 I think you are trying to fit the SQL engine into your mindset, rather than the other way round. Use the database in the way it's designed, as an efficient set-based datastore, not trying to bash it into a procedural, imperative mindset of "bunch of rows that I need to loop".

Comment: "I think you are trying to fit the SQL engine into your mindset" - I think you are right @Charlieface. I'm having trouble seeing how I could sort by anything other than the unique id column with cursor based pagination - especially when that column is generated, such as "distance to (x, y)" - but judging from the feedback so far, it's probably possible. I'll do some more digging, starting from your link. Thank you!

Comment: I have set up a repository at https://github.com/FelixZY/dynamic-query-cursor-pagination-example to further explore the cursor based pagination on dynamically generated columns. Right now it is more of a problem statement than a solution but hopefully it can serve as an example once I've had time to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL.

You can count how many rows are in the table whose values are less than the parameter. For example:

```
select count(*) from t where name < 'aaaa'; -- 0
select count(*) from t where name < 'dddd'; -- 3
select count(*) from t where name < 'aaa';  -- 0
select count(*) from t where name < 'aabb'; -- 1
select count(*) from t where name < 'gggg'; -- 6
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0AQ6bZhM).

Comment: I'm actually hoping to apply the answer to this question to multiple dialects of SQL but Postgres is one of them :) .

Comment: This does work. However, I'm concerned about its efficiency (see [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tlXn5CXi)). Even with an index, this results in a sequential scan rather than making use of the fact that the list is sorted.

Comment: In the best case scenario the engine will need to scan the index to find the position of the new entry. Now, for thousands of rows (i.e. less than 100k) I would not be concerned; caches will resolve that behind the scenes once the data gets hot (after you have ran the same query a few times).

Comment: The other option is to store the `#` in the database itself and index it. That would be very efficient. But as soon as you add/remove an entry it would become stale. Finally, why do you want to know this number? Let the engine insert and remove entries by itself; it would do it efficiently without the need of this number.

Comment: I want to do cursor based pagination on a dataset where the given cursor key may not be present (multiple distinct data sources). Since a client may request the data to be sorted on different columns in different ways, I don't think I can store the data in a pre-optimized way. However, since I'm including an "ORDER BY" clause in the query, it should be possible to optimize the lookup using binary search. Example a similar pagination (where the key is assumed to be present):  https://github.com/dansdata-se/api/blob/5c7e788d40006097a258be5dbfe456cb260fa25f/src/db/venues/index.ts#L162-L194